# Youtube embedded video will only have audio when iPhone not muted

Tags: iphone, audio, video, youtube

I'm developing a mobile website which includes Youtube embedded videos, I am doing this through the `<iframe>` tag:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoID" frameborder="0" width="560" height="315"></iframe>
```

The video embeds OK, and plays as expected, but when the iPhone has the silent switch to Muted, no audio comes out, (with headphones the audio is OK). Whenever I un-mute the iPhone, the speakers work fine and the Youtube video works perfectly...

Is there a way I can override the iPhone silent switch so that the speakers play the video even when the iPhone is muted?

Many apps, including the native Youtube app work fine with the speakers even when the iPhone is muted, since these are all user-initiated audio events...

Comment: Who'd have thunk that the mute switch would... you know... mute the audio?

Answer (score 3):

No, Apple allows it's users to have this option to respect their privacy. There are times when everyone needs to have their phones be silent. iPhone wouldn't be much of a phone if it didn't allow that.

Comment: The silent switch on the iPhone is supposed to mute only notification alerts, phonecall alerts and non user-initiated audio, such as background music on apps.. It should not mute audio triggered by the user, such as when tapping play on a youtube video...

Comment: You're right, but you understand that the user has control of that volume as well right? And if their silent switch is set to silent, the default volume (set by the user) is typically muted as well.

Comment: Yes I know that, the thing is that the exact same iPhone setup which mutes MY embedded video does not mute videos in other apps, i.e. the native youtube app...